# MalformedPolicyDocument error when creating policy via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am getting the following error when running terraform:

```
* aws_iam_role_policy.rds_policy: Error putting IAM role policy my-rds-policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: The policy failed legacy parsing
```

Here is my definition of the resource:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "rds_policy" {
  name = "my-rds-policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.rds_role.id}"
  policy = <<EOF
  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "s3:ListBucket",
              "s3:GetBucketLocation"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
          ]
      },
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "s3:GetObjectMetaData",
              "s3:GetObject",
              "s3:PutObject",
              "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
              "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/backups/*"
          ]
      }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

The JSON policy doc is well formed, and I can't see anything obvious.

Comment: That first left brace after the EOF looks like it's indented when it shouldn't be. What happens if you unindent that? The heredoc stuff can be pretty particular at times.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Wow, bizarrely that worked. Post that as an answer and I will mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to make sure that you don't have any indentation at the start of your EOF [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) because your JSON policy should not start with an indented brace.

So you should be fine with this small change:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "rds_policy" {
  name = "my-rds-policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.rds_role.id}"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "s3:ListBucket",
              "s3:GetBucketLocation"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
          ]
      },
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "s3:GetObjectMetaData",
              "s3:GetObject",
              "s3:PutObject",
              "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
              "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/backups/*"
          ]
      }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively change `<<EOF` to `<<-EOF` to allow indentation. 
It will then remove the number of indentation matching the line with fewest indentations at apply.

Comment: Be careful though not to use directives with leading whitespace trimming %{~...} in the heredoc as this messes up the indentation and is a right pain to workout workout why it complain that your first character is not '{'

Comment: The use of `<<-EOF` is tempting but it only works when indentation uses tabs not spaces.  See [this stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76481/cant-indent-heredoc-to-match-code-blocks-indentation) for much more on shell heredocs.