# Terraform: pass variable as a parameter in azure policy initiative

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy

I have a custom policy initiative I would like to assign using terraform, one of the policies does have parameters.
I know that for single policy assignment, we could use something like this, and pass variable as parameter.

```
 parameters = jsonencode({
    "operationName": {
      "value": var.allowed_values,
    }
  })
```

however, I tried this with initiative, this doesn't seem to like it keeps complaining parameter is missing.

Infact, I tried to hardcode parameter into the body of azurerm_policy_assignment, I don't think even this is working.

```
resource "azurerm_policy_assignment" "example" {
  name                 = "mcs_governance_policy_assignment"
  scope                = var.scopes
  policy_definition_id = azurerm_policy_set_definition.iam.id
  description          = "example"
  display_name         = "Governance Policy"

  metadata = <<METADATA
    {
    "category": "General"
    }
METADATA
  parameters = <<PARAMETERS
    {
     "operationName": {
        "value": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/write" 
      }
  }
PARAMETERS

}
```

the policy initiative definition policy is as following, it uses built in policy, I have not included all the policies in this initiative, just for the one that complaining about the parameter

```
resource "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "iam" {

  name         = "mcs_iam"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  display_name = "MCS IAM Governance Policy Set"
  description  = "Contains MCS Governance policies"

  metadata = <<METADATA
    {
    "category": "General"
    }

METADATA

    policy_definition_reference {
    # An activity log alert should exist for specific Policy operations
    policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/c5447c04-a4d7-4ba8-a263-c9ee321a6858"
    reference_id         = "MCS IAM 3.1"
  }
```

Comment: "I don't think even this is working." - what do you mean by this? Any error messages?

Comment: It would help if you showed your error message but it may well be that it doesn't like the indentation. You can either remove the indentation or use the flushing heredoc as mentioned in the two answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42670283/2291321.

Comment: Hi All, the error message is the same for both "Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="MissingPolicyParameter" Message="The policy set definition 'mcs_iam' is missing the parameter(s) 'operationName' as defined in the policy definition 'c5447c04-a4d7-4ba8-a263-c9ee321a6858'."

Comment: From the error it seems like the issue may be with the `azurerm_policy_set_definition.iam` resource. What does that look like?

Comment: Hi I have edited with the initiative definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, the `azurerm_policy_set_definition` `iam` only reference the policy definition, but it does not set the parameters in the policy_definition_reference block for the property [`parameter_values`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/policy_set_definition#parameter_values). You don't show how the policy definition configured, so you need to check how do the parameters setting in the policy definition and then add the parameter setting in the policy set definition.